How make Laravel Sushi Models Many to Many Relationships
:D
I can't make a Many to Many Relationships between
two Laravel Sushi Models.
For example, I have two sushi models: Product and Category. I want to make a many-to-many relationship between them.
Model\Product.php
class Product extends Model
{
    use Sushi;

    protected $rows = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Product 1',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Product 2',
        ],
    ];

    /** @return BelongsToMany<Category> */
    public function categories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

Model\Category.php
class Category extends Model
{
    use Sushi;

    protected $rows = [
        [
            'id' => 10,
            'name' => 'Category 1',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 11,
            'name' => 'Category 2',
        ],
    ];

    /** @return BelongsToMany<Product> */
    public function products(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}

If I try to load the values I get this error:
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->load('categories');
/*
Illuminate Database QueryException  PHP 8.3.8 Laravel Framework 11.8.0
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: category_product
*/

I understand that by default, Laravel wants this table for the "Many to Many Relationships", but:
How could I get around having to create this table and have the data be static?
Similar to Sushi's getRows() method.
I need it to allow me to put "static" data so that I can replace it with my real data source.
I get the data from an external request and receive it in this format:
Product:
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "categories": [
        10,
        11
    ]
}

Category:
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "products": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}

Thanks in advance and best regards!
Test input
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->load('categories');

Expected output
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Category 1"
        }
    ]
}

